# multiple servers running the same thing, how?

Tags: networking, ip

I have a little issue that I don't understand well enough to answer myself.

Basically I have some servers on my home network, I am wondering how 2 servers could run something, lets say apache in this case, on the same ports and on the same external IP, but be able to access them both?

I'm using a BT Hub 5, it allows me to port forward to only 1 server per port or it causes a conflict, do I need a better/business router or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how this is off-topic? It's a question about something I didn't understand about a networking on a server, the question was answered very well and I have resolved my problem and I'm sure many other people with the same problem will benefit from this too. Also for minimal understanding I already knew this was possible by using different ports, but that's not what I wanted. Sorry if I am wrong, not trying to start a debate here either, just stating that I don't think it was off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a load-balancer or a reverse proxy as public-facing component.

This component will listen on external/public IP and routes requests to your servers depending on chosen load-balancing algorithm.

**Edit, based on comments :**

As you want to serve *several* websites, you need a reverse-proxy (HAProxy and others) It can be in its own DMZ (as long as it can access backend servers) or in same vlan as servers (not recommended)

A standard setup is (from internet to backend)

1. Router / FW
2. Proxy (which can also manage ssl endpoints) in its own DMZ
3. Backend application servers in their own VLAN.
4. Database in another VLAN

Between each VLAN, only allowed ports opened on FW.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Just had a quick search on load balancers and I'm not sure if this is what I need, the servers will be running completely different websites/applications, can you confirm it is still a load balancer that I need?

Comment: Yes you need something like HAPRoxy and check the host header

Comment: Thank you :) Looking a little further into this would I use the HAPRoxy in a DMZ? Or is that not necessary, sorry for the double question.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether haproxy is in the DMZ or not, as long as it can directly reach each of the individual backends. In practice that means haproxy does live in the DMZ.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, really useful and I am ready to go, thank you all.